# How to split a user-generated string which may contain the delimitter?

Tags: c#, csv

I'd like to String.Split() the following string using a comma as the delimitter:

```
John,Smith,123 Main Street,212-555-1212
```

The above content is entered by a user.  If they enter a comma in their address, the resulting string would cause problems to String.Split() since you now have 5 fields instead of 4:

```
John,Smith,123 Main Street, Apt 101,212-555-1212
```

I can use String.Replace() on all user input to replace commas with something else, and then use String.Replace() again to convert things back to commas:

```
value = value.Replace(",", "*");
```

However, this can still be fooled if a user happens to use the placeholder delimitter "*" in their input.  Then you'd end up with extra commas and no asterisks in the result.

I see solutions online for dealing with escaped delimitters, but I haven't found a solution for this seemingly common situation.  What am I missing?

EDIT: This is called [delimitter collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#Delimiter_collision).

Comment: How is your problem different from the ones solved by escaped delimiters? I.e. why not escape the delimiters?

Comment: You say you can replace commas on all user input which sounds like the values are separate at that point. Why are they then stuffed together into a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One foolproof solution would be to convert the user input to base64 and then delimit with a comma. It will mean that you will have to convert back after parsing.

Comment: Excellent.  Many thanks.  This never would have occurred to me.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common scenario — you have some arbitrary string values that you would like to compose into a structure, which is itself a string, but without allowing the values to interfere with the delimiters in structure around them.

You have several options:

1. **Input restriction**: If it is acceptable for your scenario, the simplest solution is to restrict the use of delimiters in the values. In your specific case, this means disallow commas.
2. **Encoding**: If input restriction is not appropriate, the next easiest option would be to encode the entire input value. Choose an encoding that does not have delimiters in its range of possible outputs (e.g. Base64 does not feature commas in its encoded output)
3. **Escaping delimiters**: A slightly more complex option is to come up with a convention for escaping delimiters. If you're working with something mainstream like CSV it is likely that the problem of escaping is already solved, and there's a standard library that you can use. If not, then it will take some thought to come up with a complete escaping system, and implement it.

If you have the flexibility to not use CSV for your data representation this would open up a host of other options. (e.g. Consider the way in which parameterised SQL queries sidestep the complexity of input escaping by storing the parameter values separately from the query string.)

Answer (score 3):

This may not be an option for you but would is it not be easier to use a very uncommon character, say a pipe |, as your delimiter and not allow this character to be entered in the first instance?

Comment: Yes, that's what my original code did.  It works fine, but I was looking for a more general solution.

Comment: Fair point Bob wasn't sure if you'd tried the simple solution from you original question. Do like the base64 answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

If this is [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), the address should be surrounded by quotes. CSV parsers are widely available that take this into account when parsing the text.

```
John,Smith,"123 Main Street, Apt. 6",212-555-1212
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting quotes, or some other begin and end delimiters, around each of the user inputs, and ignore any special character between a set of quotes.

This really comes down to a situation of cleansing user inputs.  You should only allow desired characters in the user input and reject/strip invalid inputs from the user.  This way you could use your asterisk delimiter.

The best solution is to define valid characters, and reject non valid characters somehow, then use the nonvalid character (which will not appear in the input since they are "banned") as you delimiters

Comment: Why the downvote?  Especially when I started by suggesting what is currently the most upvoted answer, while trying to bring to light a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Dont allow the user to enter that character which you are using as a Delimiter. I personally feel this is best way.

Answer (score 0):

Funny solution (works if the address is the only field with coma):

Split the string by coma. First two pieces will be name and last name; the last piece is the telephone - take those away. Combine the rest by coma back - that would be address ;)

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, the user is *already* "escaping" the comma with the space afterward.

So, try this:

```
string[] values = RegEx.Split(value, ",(?![ ])");
```

The user can still break this if they don't put a space, and there is a more foolproof method (using the standard CSV method of quoting values that contain commas), but this will do the trick for the use case you've presented.

One more solution: provide an "Address 2" field, which is where things like apartment numbers would traditionally go. User can still break it if they are lazy, though what they'll actually break the fields *after* address2.

Answer (score -1):

Politely remind your users that properly-formed street addresses in the United States and Canada should NEVER contain any punctuation whatsoever, perhaps?

The process of automatically converting corrupted data into useful data is non-trivial without heuristic logic.  You could try to outsource the parsing by calling a third-party address-formatting library to apply the USPS formatting rules.

Even USPS requires the user to perform much of the work, by having components of the address entered into distinct fields on their address "canonicalizer" page (http://zip4.usps.com/zip4/welcome.jsp).

Comment: I wanted to support addresses outside of the US and Canada though.